# \raggedcolumns messes up last paragraph in multicol-environment

Tags: multicol

In the following MWE, `multicols` `\raggedcolumns` is employed to make sure that lines next to each other are about level. This works just fine. However, the last paragraph is a bit messed up. (The gibberish-text at the end is to reproduce this outcome.)

```
\documentclass[paper=140mm:210mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} \raggedcolumns  
\small \lipsum[1] \lipsum[1]

 wrhgäe rgj alökgn aer äjgv bnae räo ugth \normalsize
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

How can one make the last two lines of the right column level to the second-to-last und third-to-last line of the left column? Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete the `\normalsize` then you get baseline alignment

[image]

`\normalsize` in that position does not affect any fonts in the document, its only effect is to force the final paragraph to be set with small text on a normalsize baseline spacing.

Comment: I wanted to switch back to `\normalsize`d font after the multicolumn-content is printed. The thin page-format would have made it difficult typeset the page with `\normalsize`, as there is too much white space between the words, then. That’s why I used `\small`. In hindsight it obviously looks pretty stupid to having switched in the environment. Thanks.

Comment: @Kubo the font is restored at the end of the environment anyway so it has no effect on the following document but a font size should always  be _after_ a paragraph and include the end of the paragraph. If you put the `\normalsize` in the paragraph as you have it then the entire last paragraph is set with the baseline spacing set by `\normalsize.